# Unit test a flask app but avoid it calling other methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a small Python (Flask) app that is listening on port 8080 for a POST request.
I am writing some UnitTests, but I was wondering how can I **avoid a call** that it makes to another method for e.g on **LINE number 11** in my **unit test**. I just want to be able to test the POST and validate the response code is 200 if correct info is passed.

**main.py**

```
1 @app.route("/endpoint/", methods=['POST'])
2 def mypostmethod():
3
4    if 'Content-Type' in request.headers and request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
5        post_data = request.json
6
7        req_data = request.get_json()
8        content = req_data['content']
9
10       #####--How to avoid this in unit test--start--
11       result = someClass.someMethod(content)
12       #####--How to avoid this in unit test--end--
13
14       return content
15
16   else:
17   if not 'Content-Type' in request.headers:
18       return Response("No Content-Type set in request header", status='400')
19
20   if request.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/json':
21       return Response("Content-Type in request header should be application/json", status='400')
```

My unit test looks like this:

**test_main.py**

```
import json
import main
import unittest

content = 'hello'

class PublicTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = main.app.test_client()

    def test_send_valid_request(self):
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        request_body = {
            'content': content
        }

        response = self.app.post('/endpoint',
                                 headers=headers,
                                 data=json.dumps(request_body),
                                 follow_redirects=True)

        assert response.status_code == 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently used this way to fire the method only if pytest was NOT the sys.argv. but it can work with unittest too.
Like so 

`10       #####--How to avoid this in unit test--start--
-10      if not any(['unittest' in arg for arg in sys.argv]): 
-10           # eval to false when running the cmd pytest 
11            result = someClass.someMethod(content)
12       #####--How to avoid this in unit test--end--`

Another way would be to set an env var at runtime on your fixture. 
Hope this can help.

---

Btw this code is not tested so there may be syntax err it is just to give you and idea.